# Trying to get property of non-object in View in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I think I'm doing something wrong when trying to render data passed to views.

Here's my route, where I build a simple array:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $data = [];

    foreach(App\User::all() as $user) {
        foreach($user->orders as $order) {
            foreach ($order->sub_orders as $sub_order) {
                $data[] = 
                    [
                        'customer_id' => $user->id, 
                        'customer_name' => $user->name, 
                        'city' => $user->city, 
                        'order_id' => $order->id, 
                        'order_date' => $order->created_at->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                        'sub_order_id' => $sub_order->id,
                        'item_name' => $sub_order->item->name,
                        'quantity' => $sub_order->quantity,
                        'unit_price' => $sub_order->item->unit_price,
                        'total_price' => $sub_order->item->unit_price * $sub_order->quantity,
                        'delivery_date' => $sub_order->delivery_date,
                        'delivery_status' => $sub_order->delivery_status
                    ];
            }
        }
    }

    return view('welcome', ["data" => $data]);
});
```

And here's how I'm attempting it on the view side:

```
@foreach ($data as $row)
  <tr>
    <td> {{ $row->customer_id }} </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

This gives me the error `Trying to get property of non-object` on the line `<td> {{ $row->customer_id }} </td>`. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. :|

Also, is there any way to `dd` or `var_dump` the data received in the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$row` is array and not object. And you can access it via

```
$row['customer_id'];
```

PS: Yeah you can use `print_r($data);` in the view to see it or can use `var_dump` or `dd`.

Comment: Or `dump($data)` is also possible.

Comment: I guess we need to use the PHP tags for these functions, right?

Comment: You can place these functions inside `{{ }}` and it will work too :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$row->customer_id` with `$row['customer_id']` to access `array` value;

Answer (score 0):

`$row` is an associative array.  You can to this:

```
@foreach ($data as $row)
  <tr>
      <td> {{ $row['customer_id'] }} </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

`$row` is not an object, its an associative array. Access it like this

```
$row['customer_id'];
```

you can use `dd` to see data :)